How is this function $\Delta_1^1$?
I am trying to read Jech's set theory (self-study only since I am from a different field so please bear with me) and in the Chapter about constructible sets, it is shown that the function
$$
\alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}
$$
is $\Delta_1$ (i.e. both $\Sigma_1^1$ and $\Pi_1$), where $\alpha$ denotes an ordinal and $L_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$th constructible set as defined by transfinite induction, i.e. $L_{0} = \emptyset$ and $L_{\alpha+1} = \text{def}(L_{\alpha})$ and $\text{def}$ refers to the closure of the Godel operations.
To show that $\alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}$ is $\Delta_1$, Jech showed (Lemma 13.14) that $\alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}$ is $\Sigma_1$, but he omitted the part of showing that $\alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}$ is also $\Pi_1$, perhaps because it is supposed to be obvious. However, it is not very obvious for me how $\alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}$ is also $\Pi_1$.
So far, what I know is that I have to come up with a $\Pi_1$ definition for the graph of $F: \alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}$, i.e. some attempt:
$$
(\alpha,L_{\alpha}) \in \text{graph}(\alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}) \iff \forall X (F(\alpha) = X \rightarrow X = L_{\alpha})
$$
Since $F(\alpha)=X$ is in the antecedent and Jech proved that this is $\Sigma_1$, then its negation is $\Pi_1$. But I am not sure if the $\forall X$ part above suffices for the definition to be $\Pi_1$ and I still have to prove that $X = L_{\alpha}$ is also $\Pi_1$.
(edit: fyi, apparently the answer lies in Lemma 13.10 (vii) of Jech)

Any (total) $\Sigma_1$ function $F$ is automatically $\Pi_1$ also. If $F(x)=y$ is expressed by a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\sigma(x,y)$, then it is also expressed by $\forall z\,(\sigma(x,z)\to z=y)$, which is (logically equivalent to) a $\Pi_1$ formula.
If you're worried that $\alpha\mapsto L_\alpha$ isn't total, being defined only for ordinals $\alpha$, just extend it in some trivial way to become total. In general, having a $\Delta_1$ domain is, in this context, as good as being total.
Also, the $\Sigma,\Pi,\Delta$ in the question should not have the superscript $1$. With the superscript, these symbols refer to the projective (or analytical) hierarchy, whereas you want the Lévy hierarchy of set theory.

ok thanks for this, just to clarify, how does having a $\Delta_1$ domain allow one to trivially extend a partial function to become total ?

okay got it, I just removed the superscripts ... am working on recursion theory and my mind got mixed up

ok, i just saw Lemma 13.10 (vii) of Jech and apparently there's a way to "convert" a $\Sigma_1$ function definition to $\Pi_1$ given a $\Delta_1$ domain without extending the function to become total ...

$X$ is $L_\alpha$ iff every "$L$-building sequence of length $\alpha$" ends in $X$.
Here, an $L$-building sequence of length $\alpha$ is a sequence $(S_\eta)_{\eta\le \alpha}$ of sets such that $S_0=\emptyset$, $S_\lambda=\bigcup_{\gamma<\lambda}S_\gamma$ for $\lambda\le\alpha$ limit, and $S_{\gamma+1}=Def(S_\gamma)$ for $\gamma<\alpha$. The point is that being an $L$-building sequence of length $\alpha$ is an appropriately simple property.

okay thanks, so that means that the statement $(\alpha,L_{\alpha}) \in \text{graph}(\alpha \rightarrow L_{\alpha}) \iff \forall X (F(\alpha) = X \rightarrow X = L_{\alpha})$ is $\Pi_1^1$ given that the consequent in the implication (i.e. $X=L_{\alpha}$ is $\Pi_1^1$) as you pointed out ? i.e. every $L$-building sequence of length $\alpha$ ends in $X$
